# How to create Int32 through UnsafePointer<Int32>?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to get a value of `Int32` through an `Int32 Pointer`.

```
var result:Int32 = 32
var y = withUnsafePointer(&result, {(point:UnsafePointer<Int32>) -> UnsafePointer<Int32> in
    return point
})
```

Comment: Did you try standard pointer deferencing semantics?

Comment: @borrrden i just find i can also get the pointer with "&result",i just want to create a Variables through the pointer

Comment: ....and what about `*`??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is like every UnsafePointer<>. Example: `NSErrorPointer` which is an `AutoreleasingUnsafePointer<NSError?>` you can get the value with the memory attribute.

Use the attribute `memory`

```
var errPtr: UnsafePointer<NSError> = ...
var err: NSError = errPtr.memory // not optional
```

Solution to your example is very easy then:

```
var result:Int32 = 32
var y = withUnsafePointer(&result, {(point:UnsafePointer<Int32>) -> UnsafePointer<Int32> in
    return point
    })
y.memory // in the playground it shows 32 :-D
```

---

There is no dereference operator in Swift, in C it was the aterisk `*`, but that is not possible in Swift.

---

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH8-XID_16) is very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The type `UnsafePointer<Memory>` has a subscript operator. Provided that the pointer points to something, subscript 0 always exists, so this works in a playground and it has the advantage that the reference guide has the subscript documented but not the `memory` property.

```
var result:Int32 = 32
var y = withUnsafePointer(&result, {(point:UnsafePointer<Int32>) -> UnsafePointer<Int32> in
    return point
})

y[0]  // 32
```

Comment: y is a pointer, so y[0] is its memory. Correct, but a little confusing, for that it is not actually an array. You inspired me, and thank you.

Comment: @DawnSong be aware that there are big changes for unsafe pointers coming in Swift 3.